# IntelliJ IDEA not showing JavaFX in the new project wizard

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, jetbrains-ide

I was following [create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) help topic, but I cannot find JavaFx in the left menu as shown in the help topic. I am using IntelliJ Community edition (2020.3.1).

According to [JetBrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) both community and ultimate editions support JavaFx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the linked help topic](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#add-javafx-lib) there is a info bubble just below the "Create a new project" section saying following

> If you cannot find JavaFX in the New Project wizard, make sure that
> the bundled JavaFX plugin is enabled in Settings/Preferences |
> Plugins.

So you have to enable JavaFx plugin in order to see JavaFx option in the new projects left menu.